# Side menu doesn't refresh untill open the app again

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my application,I show user-name at side-menu header with ng-bind.
This user-name is comes from local-storage. But when i edit user-profile and also user-name,and override it to local-storage.
After that the new username is not showing to the sidemenu-header.
But when i refresh the page from browser or reopen the application,it shows new one efficiently.
So what should i do for refresh the content of side-menu (user-name) ??
It take slot of my time....
answer will be appreciated...
Thanks :)

hi,anied
Thanks for replying.
I share my code below....

### Login page

I set the first_name and last name to the local-storage that comes from service response.
and login-page URL is==> http://localhost:8100/#/login

localStorage.setItem("firstname",JSON.stringify($scope.dataa.first_name));              localStorage.setItem("lastname",JSON.stringify($scope.dataa.last_name));

and i get it to my ionic menu controller....
var firstname={};
var lastname={};
$scope.firstname=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('firstname'));  $scope.lastname=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lastname'));

and url of this is==>http://localhost:8100/#/menu/dashboard1
a root page 'menu'.

When i edit page, i set this content again to local-storage.But it not showing to menu header.But when i refresh the page it shows efficiently.
I think this is the root url problem==> /menu/ is never refresh in this app.

I edit this content with this url==>/localhost:8100/#/menu/editprofile
so,it not refresh root url page.
But when i edit profile with this url==>/localhost:8100/#/editprofile
it,refresh content automatically....
and not for above url.
Hope you understand.
answer will be appriciated.
thanks

Comment: Please provide some of your code

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your code, my hunch is to try doing a $scope apply inside of a timeout:

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Do the above after you have changed the bound data and see if that forces a refresh of the UI.

(Incidentally, if you are attempting to bind the data *directly to localStorage*, I doubt that that will work -- you probably either need to hold the data in memory, or bind to a function that fetches it from localStorage, depending on your needs.)